# водоросль и водное растение

Tags: семантика

Есть ли на бытовом уровне существенная разница между водорослями и водными растениями? Если да, то как это объяснить школьнику?

Вопрос исходно был из школьной ботаники. В задании надо было нарисовать водоросли или даже собрать гербарий. Всякие там кувшинки и тростники почему-то не подошли. Это было давно, но сейчас возник аналогичный вопрос в контексте аквариумов.

Comment: На бытовом уровне водоросли - частный случай водных растений - полностью находятся под водой. На более научном - это _не совсем_ растения (см. напр. википедию https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8).

Comment: @Alex_ander В аквариуме что растет?

Comment: Там водоросли (не лилии и не лотосы).

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял ситуацию, как связан гербарий с аквариумом, поэтому отвечаю, что знаю, без привязки к контексту.

В бытовом понимании водоросли - простейшие водные растения, не имеющие структурно оформленного разделения органов на корень,листья, стебель и т.п. Это определение дает БТС Кузнецова.

В биологии: внесистемная группа (таксон), объединяющая по внешним признакам представителей совершенно разных системных таксонов - вплоть до разных семейств.

В аквариумистике: полезная ("культурная") растительность - растения, сорная - водоросли. Последнее не совсем правильно, ибо сорные для аквариума растения могут быть и не водорослями ни в каком понимании, но в огромном большинстве случаев засоряют аквариум именно водоросли в биологическом понимании, более того, таких агрессивных аквариумных сорняков (и других культурных водоемов) всего два или три таксона, прежде всего это нитчатка (подгруппа зеленых водорослей - Chlorophyta). Вот её-то прежде всего и называют аквариумисты водорослью.